# left regular grammar to nfa

Tags: parsing, grammar, finite-automata, automata

I can convert a right regular grammar to an Non deterministic finite automata with the following algorithm:

```
inputAlphabet = terminals grammar
states = final + nonTerminals grammar
startState = startSymbol grammar
acceptStates = ["final"]
transitionFunction = relationTable
```

where the relationship table is generated by taking the grammar productions and following these rules

```
Nonterminal -> empty = Nonterminal (on empty) -> final
Nonterminal -> Terminal = Nonterminal (on Terminal) -> final
Nonterminal1 -> Terminal Nonterminal2 = Nontermal1 (on Terminal) -> Nonterminal2
```

What algorithm would I follow to convert a left regular grammar to a finite automata? A left linear grammar follows this style:

```
Nonterminal -> empty
Nonterminal -> Terminal
Nonterminal -> Nonterminal Terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the left linear grammar to right linear grammar by swapping the positions of non-terminals from left to right and then create the FA using your algorithm and then just reverse the FA to get the language generated by original left linear grammar.